# android virtual device is currently running in an emulator and cannot be deleted in appuse

Tags: android, android-securityexception, android-security

Even though emulator is not running in AppUse, when I try to delete AVD file am getting error:

> Android virtual device is currently running in an emulator and cannot be deleted

How to solve it?

[image: error]

Comment: May be restart adb will work for you

Comment: Its worked after deleting avd from \.android\avd :)

Comment: @Abhilash Thanks, that worked for me too. Should be the answer rather than a comment.